# Check event handler parameter

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I got this code when learning JavaScript:

```
myLink.onmouseover = showLinkAttr;
function showLinkContent(evt) {
    if (evt) {
        var url = evt.target;
    }
    else {
        evt = window.event;
        var url = evt.srcElement;
    }
..............
```

I don't know why we need to check event handler parameter `evt` before creating it. My thinking here is this code is redundant because `evt` doesn't exist (this code is in the beginning of the script file), show we should create it without checking it, like this:

```
  myLink.onmouseover = showLinkAttr;
  function showLinkContent(evt) {
        evt = window.event;
        var url = evt.srcElement;
```

However, as I am new to JavaScript, and the code below was written by an expert. So, could you tell me why she using it instead of the one I wrote below?

Comment: To accept an answer on some of your other questions, you need to click the outline of the tick below the answer's rating.

Answer (score 2):

You're half way there... `evt` will *only* be undefined when the client is running that miserable excuse of a browser that is known as IE.

IE doesn't pass the event object to the handler, but has only 1 global event object. That's why your event handler checks to see if the event object has been passed as an argument, if not, it gets the global event object. This can be written a lot shorter though:

```
evt = evt || window.event;//evt is equal to itself, if it's not undefined, else it's a reference to the global object
```

Ditto for the target (you called it `var url`, which is confusing and perhaps wrong):

```
var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
```

The `target` (or `srcElement`) returns a reference to a DOM element (the one on which the event was fired), not a url, like your varname would have you believe.
The double pipe `||` is known as the default operator.

Answer (score 0):

The code is catering to the inconsistencies between different browsers. Look at this article for details: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html